# AWS lambda function to submit spark job

Tags: apache-spark, aws-lambda

I would like to use Spark-sumit REST apis in AWS lambda function to submit jobs.I have looked into Spark-Jobserver but looks like it needs to be deployed in a\n Ec2 Instance,but i would like to submit jobs using AWS Lambda function using Spark REST interface.Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You can add step to the EMR cluster from the lambda. The Step can be shell script,hive, or spark job.

The function that helps to do that is

```
emr.addJobFlowSteps(params, function(err, data)
```

I am adding the link for the api calls available  on EMR
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EMR.html

Comment: Do you have the job server in the cluster?

Comment: Im not using Spark jobserver,as i said i wan to use AWS lambda with spark REST interface

Comment: @shiv455 Do you want to submit jobs without any EC2 instance at all?

Comment: @ Sergey yes I want to submit jobs from lambda without using Ec2 instances